# Exclude type from XPath result JCR

Tags: xpath, jcr

I have the following XPath query:

```xml
//element(*, hippo:harddocument)[jcr:contains(., 'jasper')]
```

What I want to do is exclude all nodes of type `hand:iris` from the result set. How can I do this?

Comment: Please add some example document to match against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query should make it:
`"//element(*, hippo:harddocument)[jcr:contains(., 'jasper') and not(@jcr:primaryType = 'hand:iris'))]"`

BR.